# Issues Loading jqGrid with 25,000 Rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I'm having some difficulty loading my jqGrid with a big amount of rows. Once my document is ready I'm calling a Javascript function that gets a collection of objects from an API and then adds the row data to the grid. Everything has been working fine, but now I have over 20,000 rows, so the grid never loads. Is there something I can do to fix this? Is it possible to only paint the data that the user can see? For example, if the row number on the pager is set to 50, can I simply only load 50 rows and not all 25,000?

Here's my grid:

$(function () {

```
        $("#grid").jqGrid({
            datatype: "local",
            loadonce: false,
            height: "auto",
            search: true,
            title: false ,
            autowidth: true,
            shrinkToFit: true,
            searchOnEnter: true,
            colNames: ['ID', 'BDO Number', 'BDO Date', 'Delivery Date', 'Miles', 'Zip Code', 'Zone', 'Fuel Surcharge', 'Driver', 'Driver Rate', 'Total Driver Pay', 'Order', 'Driver ID',
                        'Vendor ID', 'Vendor', 'Airport', 'Airline', 'Claim Reference', 'Clear Date', 'Mileage', 'Mileage Cost', 'Special', 'Special Cost', 'Exc Cost', 'Pickup Date', 'Total Delivery Cost',
                        'Vendor Profit', 'Driver Percent', 'Driver Fuel Surcharge', 'Total Driver Reported', 'Payment', 'User Cleared', 'Excess Costs', 'Additional Fees', 'DriverCostSchemaID'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'ID', index: 'ID', hidden: true },
                { name: 'BDONumber', index: 'BDONumber', align: 'center', classes: 'gridButton' },
                { name: 'BDODate', index: 'BDODate', width: 250, align: 'center', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'l, F d, Y g:i:s A' } },
                { name: 'DeliveryDate', index: 'DeliveryDate', width: 250, align: 'center', formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'l, F d, Y g:i:s A' } },
                { name: 'Miles', index: 'Miles', width: 40, align: 'center' },
                { name: 'ZipCode', index: 'ZipCode', width: 55, align: 'center' },
                { name: 'Zone', index: 'Zone', width: 40, align: 'center' },
                { name: 'FuelFloat', index: 'FuelFloat', width: 50, align: 'center', formatter: money, sorttype: 'float' },
                { name: 'DriverName', index: 'DriverName', width: 125, align: 'center' },
                { name: 'RateFloat', index: 'RateFloat', width: 75, align: 'center', formatter: money, sorttype: 'float' },
                { name: 'PayFloat', index: 'PayFloat', width: 75, align: 'center', formatter: money, sorttype: 'float' },
                { name: 'Order', index: 'Order', hidden: true },
                { name: 'Driver', index: 'Driver', hidden: true },
                { name: 'Vendor', index: 'Vendor', hidden: true },
                { name: 'Airport', index: 'Airport', hidden: true },
                { name: 'Airline', index: 'Airline', hidden: true },
                { name: 'VendorName', index: 'VendorName', hidden: true },
                { name: 'ClaimReference', index: 'ClaimReference', hidden: true },
                { name: 'ClearDate', index: 'ClearDate', hidden: true, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'l, F d, Y g:i:s A' } },
                { name: 'Mileage', index: 'Mileage', hidden: true },
                { name: 'MileageCost', index: 'MileageCost', hidden: true, formatter: money },
                { name: 'Special', index: 'Special', hidden: true },
                { name: 'SpecialCost', index: 'SpecialCost', hidden: true, formatter: money },
                { name: 'ExcCost', index: 'ExcCost', hidden: true, formatter: money },
                { name: 'PickupDate', index: 'PickupDate', hidden: true, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'l, F d, Y g:i:s A' } },
                { name: 'TotalDeliveryCost', index: 'TotalDeliveryCost', hidden: true, formatter: money },
                { name: 'VendorProfit', index: 'VendorProfit', hidden: true, formatter: money },
                { name: 'DriverPercent', index: 'DriverPercent', hidden: true },
                { name: 'DriverFuelSurcharge', index: 'DriverFuelSurcharge', hidden: true, formatter: money },
                { name: 'TotalDriverReported', index: 'TotalDriverReported', hidden: true, formatter: money },
                { name: 'Payment', index: 'Payment', hidden: true },
                { name: 'UserCleared', index: 'UserCleared', hidden: true },
                { name: 'ExcCost', index: 'ExcCost', hidden: true },
                { name: 'AdditionalFees', index: 'AdditionalFees', hidden: true, formatter: money },
                { name: 'DriverCostSchemaID', index: 'DriverCostSchemaID', hidden: true },
            ],
            rowNum: 100,
            rowList: [100, 500, 1000, 100000],
            viewrecords: true,
            pager: "pager",
            sortorder: "desc",
            sortname: "DeliveryDate",
            ignoreCase: true,
            headertitles: true,
            emptyrecords: "There are no results.",           
        })

        $("#grid").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: true, defaultSearch: 'cn' });

        GetBDOs();
    });
```

And the GetBDOs function:

function GetBDOs() {

```
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("GetBDOs", "DPAdmin")",
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            async: true,
            dataType: "json"

        });

        request.done(function (results) {

            var thegrid = $("#grid");
            thegrid.clearGridData();
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                thegrid.addRowData(i + 1, results[i]);
            }
            thegrid.trigger("reloadGrid");

        });
    }
```

Which calls this:

```
        [Authorize]
        public JsonResult GetBDOs()
        {
            List<BDO> BDOs= new List<BDO>();

            // Get all BDOs
            BDOs = WebInterface.GetBDOs();

            var jsonResult = Json(BDOs.ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
            return jsonResult;
        }
```

WebInterface.GetBDOs simply hits the database and grabs all the current BDO objects, which is now between 20,000 - 25,000 and freezes the grid. Any help with this?

Comment: As Greg's answer, the pagination thing will require you to set a "LIMIT" on the database query so you retrieve the number of records your pagination will display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should be paginating that data on the server side before sending it back to the browser. Then all you need to do is fetch the next/prev page and redraw the grid.

Answer (score 1):

The part

```
var thegrid = $("#grid");
thegrid.clearGridData();

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    thegrid.addRowData(i + 1, results[i]);
}
thegrid.trigger("reloadGrid");
```

of `GetBDOs` function makes performance problems definitively. Instead of calling `addRowData` in the loop you should set `data` parameter to `results` with respect of `setGridParam`:

```
var thegrid = $("#grid");
thegrid.clearGridData();
thegrid.jqGrid("setGridParam", {data: results});
thegrid.trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Additionally it's very important to add `gridview: true` option to jqGrid.

Even better seems to me to replace use `url: "@Url.Action("GetBDOs", "DPAdmin")"` as jqGrid parameters together with `datatype: "json"` and `loadonce: true`. It will makes the same Ajax call to the server and fill the grid with all 20000 or 25000 rows of data, but placing only 100 first rows in the grid.

One more recommendation will be to use `key: true` property in `ID` column. It will inform jqGrid to use the value from `ID` column as rowid (the value of `id` attributes of `<tr>` elements of the grid). You should consider additionally to remove a lot of hidden columns and saves the data only in the internal `data` option of the grid.